# How to check whether an application is open in browser session?

Tags: asp.net, session, browser, window

I have two separate web applications. If I am in one (say app A), I should be to click on a link or button (on page 1 of A) to go to the other application’s a page (Page 1 of B).  If app B is open in a browser window, I should go to it. Should not open a new window. If app B is not in a browser session, I should get a new window. All these needs to be in the client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a link, use the `target` attribute. If you're using JavaScript, use the second parameter to `window.open`. In both cases, these name a window - only one window of the same name will ever be opened.

Comment: Thank you.. But I need to check whether the target site is already open in the browser.. If yes i dont need to open the new window but just use that opened window... So my problem is just check whether a site (or page) is open in the browser session.. Thanh you.

Comment: It would not open a new window if you have one of the same name already opened. However, it probably would reload the content (not sure what happens if you give it the same URL, or URL that only differs in the hash - needs testing). If you don't want to use this, then you cannot do that unless you require one of the newer browsers that implement `postMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

try this use session variables and when app A load type this in page_load event :
session["App"]="A";
and on every link button click event use to check session["App"].string() for the if esle to rediret it to B and if its B dont redirect it .

Comment: thank you.. But how can i get the urls of the currently opened pages in the browser?

Comment: can use javascript for it as document.write(location.herf);

Comment: ok.. but i want to get the uri of all the open tabs/window. For the current window its fine.

Comment: you can use cookies and store every open page address by using the resquest.rawurl methord it will give you the raw url which is the current page and you then check session one by one and get data.